# JavaFX - How to set text to be shown on ComboBox without relying on toString?

Tags: java, javafx

Let's suppose I have a Person domain class:

```
public class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    (...)
```

A JavaFX `ComboBox<Person>` by default uses que Person `toString` method to show values. So if my Person `toString` method just returns `name`, the persons' names will be shown on combo box.

However, let's suppose I want to implement a `Combobox<Person> myCombo` that shows persons' emails instead of names. How can I acomplish that without having to open Person class and change its `toString` method? Thanks.

Comment: See [`ComboBox.cellFactory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#cellFactoryProperty) and [`ComboBox.converter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#converterProperty).

Comment: @fabian instead of using that answer you linked, I would suggest to use a `StringCOnverter<Person>` here.